# ERROR: prepared transaction does not exist in postgresql

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am getting following error in PostgreSQL (9.2) log while running Java EE application with JPA over Hibernate:

> ERROR:  prepared transaction with identifier "131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//fwAAAd5tKPBVp1XeAAAzfmx0Y2hpZS1ub2Rl_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//fwAAAd5tKPBVp1XeAAAzpwAAAAAAAAAA" does not exist
>   STATEMENT:  ROLLBACK PREPARED '131077_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//fwAAAd5tKPBVp1XeAAAzfmx0Y2hpZS1ub2Rl_AAAAAAAAAAAAAP//fwAAAd5tKPBVp1XeAAAzpwAAAAAAAAAA'

How can I optimize settings to avoid this error? This occurs intermittently.

Comment: Seems like a bug in your JTA / XA handling of two-phase transactions. You or the framework are trying to roll back an xact that was never prepared, or that has already been rolled back. To determine which, and find out more about what's happening, enable more detailed logging in `postgresql.conf` and/or your app framework.

Comment: You can't. That's as much information as there is. That transaction doesn't exist, so either it's already been rolled back/committed or it was never created. You can configure more logging *in `postgresql.conf`* to trace `PREPARE TRANSACTION`, `ROLLBACK PREPARED` and `COMMIT PREPARED` statements in the log files. You can also inspect the `pg_prepared_xacts` table.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The reason might be that prepared transactions are disabled by default.
To enable them, edit postgresql.conf and set a value higher than 0.

```
max_prepared_transactions = 64
```

Comment: Currently max_prepared_transactions are set to 9. Is that ok?

Comment: It depends on your application and the number of users. If you still have that problem, try to increase the value an see if it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: https://www.highgo.ca/2020/01/28/understanding-prepared-transactions-and-handling-the-orphans/
If you want to use prepared transactions, it is recommended to set this value to max_connections.